# What should the "params" argument to web3::contract::Contract::query look like?

Tags: rust, ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm trying to interact with a multisig smart contract (the Gnosis multisig) and ask for the transaction details and for the number of confirmations.

Here's the straightforward Python code for what I want to do:

```py
import json
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider

contractAddress = '0x...'

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'))

with open('contract.abi', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)

contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi=abi)
tx = contract.call().transactions(123)
confirmations = contract.call().getConfirmations(123)

print(tx)
print(confirmations)
```

Here's the Rust code I came up with so far:

```
extern crate web3;

use web3::contract::{Contract, Options};
use web3::types::Address;

fn main() {
    let (_eloop, http) = web3::transports::Http::new("https://mainnet.infura.io").unwrap();
    let web3 = web3::Web3::new(http);

    // The contract address.
    let address: Address = "0x...".parse().unwrap();

    // Access the contract
    let contract = Contract::from_json(web3.eth(), address, include_bytes!("./abi.json")).unwrap();

    // Query the contract instance
    // And this is where I'm stuck!
    let result = contract.query("transactions...");
}
```

The [documentation that I found](https://docs.rs/web3/0.3.0/web3/contract/struct.Contract.html#method.query) doesn't explain what "params" are and how they should be passed into the function.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the `Tokenize` trait, which is implemented for vecs, arrays or tuples of `Tokenizable`s, another trait which is in turn implemented for e.g. `String`, `u64`, `bool`, etc.

So if you have a `&str`, just call `.to_string()` on it to get a `String`. Or if you have a number, `.try_into::<u64>()` it. Or perhaps a combination of it, e.g. `("transactions".to_string(), 123u64)`.

How I know? `params` is of type `P`, which is generic and bound by `Tokenize` (see the `where P: Tokenize`?).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the documentation does not explain what "params" are, is that you can pass any function name that is defined and accessible publicly in the Smart-Contract itself.

`balanceOf` being a default function for any ERC-20 token, it is often put as an example.

You have to check which function is called in the Python lib you are using for that call : `contract.call().transactions(123)`. You need the exact name of that function to make a call in web3-rust `Query()`.

It might be worth having a look at the [Github web3-rust examples](https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3/tree/master/examples) too if you did not see them already.